# Convert MS Word frames to table

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice-writer, libreoffice-writer

Is there a way to convert Microsoft Word frames to table?

I use export feature of old Crystal Reports which export invoice file with every field in frame.

I'm trying to use these files in OpenOffice/LibreOffice, but these poor apps can handle only first page. If document has 2 or more pages they got confused, take eternity to open, and don't open it correctly. It gets scrambled and with missing parts.

Since, I cannot influence business app and Crystal Reports part, is there a way to convert frames to table as to make document simpler for OpenOffice/LibreOffice?